# Не могу подключится к Postgres в Python

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я никак не могу подключится к Postgres, после установки он у меня спрашивает пользователя Mech(это мой user),(Рис1) но при установке я не указывал никакого пользователя. Прочитал тут и в других форумах, что нужно исправить файл pg_hba.conf, пытался и так изменить md5 на trum, но это тоже не помогло в самом pgAdmin пытаюсь создать новый сервер, но и там ошибка в виде (скрин рис2)
[image: Рис2]. Что я делаю не так? Пожалуйста подскажите по мере возможности подробней.

Comment: Не читаете документацию по PostgreSQL.

Comment: Могли бы вместо этого помочь решить проблему, не все люди такие как вы с первого раза поймут, есть и те кому не понятны документации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы что-то изменять/получать данные из БД вам нужно создать пользователя (либо использовать текущего) и дать ему права на изменение и чтение этой БД. Я могу написать как это делается в linux из терминала. В винде понятия не имею как это работает и зачем вообще пытаться на винду БД установить =)

Comment: Я пишу Бота для Вк.Бд нужна для этих целей. У меня операционка винда что тут поделать. А есть ли способ заменить обычную виндовс терминал, на linux?

Comment: @IslamIbrakhimzhanov Если вы пишите бота, то скорее всего он должен быть установлен на сервер, где будет linux, тогда есть смысл установить бд туда и обращаться к ней с своего пк при разработке. А если вы только практикуетесь, то используйте sqlite - встроенная в python БД она состоит всего из 1 файла и очень удобна в использовании